# What defines 'partial' coverage in Intellij code coverage tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I am running Java unit tests with code coverage in IntelliJ IDEA with 'tracing' (using the default Intellij coverage tool)). I have one if-statement that always reports 'partial coverage' even though both branches are used:

[image: Screenshot]

Other if-statements are green where both paths are tested, and I've tried extracting a variable with the result of the method call. Can anyone explain why line this is reported as partial instead of complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial coverage would occur, if you have compound conditions and not all of the terms are executed. e.g.

```java
if (isEmptyString(location) && isEmptyString(name)) {
    return false;
}
```

If `isEmptyString(location)` returns `false` in all test cases, `isEmptyString(name)` is never executed. Hence "partial coverage".

This is not the case in your code, therefore I would suppose that this is a bug in the coverage tool.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. I suspected that it may have been inlining the static method (unlikely, but theoretically possible) which would mean that this one line would be more complicated than it appears, but that doesn't seem to be the case. At the moment it looks like a bug.